# Median Calculation in Access with SQL

Tags: ms-access, median

I am having a little difficulty with the Access SQL Query below. It is returning -1 and 0. -1 tells me that there is a median. The zero is there is no median( that 0 is the correct value for that median).Any help with changing the query to show the actual median value. It would really help. Thanks.

```
SELECT (((Sum(IIf([CALCAULATION]<=[CALCULATION],1,0)))>=(Count(*)/2)) And ((Sum(IIf([CALCULATION]>=[CALCULATION],1,0)))>=(Count(*)/2))) AS Median, 
Datatable.Measure
FROM Datatable
WHERE (((Datatable.Date) Between #1/1/2014# And #1/31/2014#) AND ((Datatable.NAME)="Test"))
GROUP BY Datatable.Measure
ORDER BY Datatable.Measure;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  I hope you find my answer useful.  It seems you messed up your question, re-post more info at the end of your answer if you want a more sensible solution.  As they say.... as a silly question ... get a silly answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because  `[CALCAULATION]=[CALCULATION]` will always be true
and because (SUM( 1) always = COUNT(*)

This

```
      SELECT (((SUM( 1)
               )>=(COUNT(*)/2
               )
```

will evaluate to true

so

```
      SELECT (((SUM( 1)
               )>=(COUNT(*)/2
               )
         )
         AND
         ((SUM( 1
              )
           )>=(COUNT(*)/2)
         )) AS Median
```

is the same as `true and true` which is `true` ie 1.

This is clearly not what you had in mind.

[Here's a google search to help](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=calculating+mediam&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=8yQVVvfKDMubgwS9jo6oBg#q=calculating+median+in+sql)

of which I would recommend [this link](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-median.html)

Here is you SQL reformatted

```
  SELECT (((SUM( IIF([CALCAULATION]<=[CALCULATION],1,0))
           )>=(COUNT(*)/2
               )
         )
         AND
         ((SUM( IIF([CALCULATION]>=[CALCULATION],1,0)
              )
           )>=(COUNT(*)/2)
         )) AS Median
       , Datatable.Measure
    FROM Datatable
   WHERE (Datatable.Date BETWEEN #1/1/2014# AND #1/31/2014#
          AND 
          Datatable.NAME="Test"
         )
GROUP BY Datatable.Measure
ORDER BY Datatable.Measure;
```

PART 2

Here's some SQL you have used to create a median (see NameNeededHereIThink and my comments).  You might also need to add a WHERE clause to limi the dates to one month as in your previous example.  NOTE the tables MUST be the same (or contain the same data!)

```
 SELECT CALCULATION AS Median
        -- #HARVEY  You might want to add the next lines
        , a3.MEASURE
        , a3.CALCULATION

  FROM ( SELECT a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION
              , COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) Rank
           FROM Datatable_CALCULATION a1
              , Datatable_CALCULATION a2   
                --#HARVEy a1 and a2 MUST be the same table!
          WHERE a1.CALCULATION < a2.CALCULATION
             OR (a1.CALCULATION=a2.CALCULATION
                 AND 
                 a1.MEASURE    <= a2.MEASURE)
       GROUP BY a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION
       --#HARVEY REMOVED NEXT LINE
       -- as order by in sub query cannot be relied upon
       -- and was only added here for testing purposes
       -- ORDER BY a1.CALCULATION DESC
       )
       a3
 WHERE Rank =
       -- as 99/2 = 45.5 you may need to round down 
       -- tot the  nearest integer
       (SELECT cint( ((COUNT()) /2) ) AS NameNeededHereIThink
       -- (SELECT ((COUNT()+1) /2) 
          FROM Datatable_CALCULATION
       );
```

Comment: Thanks.I am still running into issues.The link was really helpful.I keep getting a syntax error in the last statement,(SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) DIV 2 FROM Datatable_CALCULATION), of the my revised SQL below. SELECT CALCULATION AS Median FROM (SELECT a1.MEASURE, a1.CALCULATION, COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) Rank FROM Datatable_CALCULATION a1, Datatable_0114_CALCULATION a2 WHERE a1.CALCULATION < a2.CALCULATION OR (a1.CALCULATION=a2.CALCULATION AND a1.MEASURE <= a2.MEASURE) group by a1.MEASURE, a1.CALCULATION
order by a1.CALCULATION desc) a3 WHERE Rank = (SELECT (COUNT(*)+1) DIV 2 FROM Datatable_CALCULATION);

Comment: See part 2 which may help!

Comment: Thanks. I am confused on the last where statement. I keep getting an error in mine.   WHERE Rank =
     ((SELECT cint(((COUNT()) DIV 2)) As Median 
        (SELECT ((COUNT()+1) DIV 2) 
          FROM Datatable_CALCULATION
       ))

Comment: see NameNeededHereIThink  in my answer!  What error message do you get!

Comment: The error message is that I have a syntax error. I thought your comments about name needed here referred to the naming of a median column. Can you clarify please? Thank you.

Comment: -- is a comment character in SQL so anything after it should not be included in your SQL.  ie use 

Rank =
       (SELECT cint( ((COUNT()) DIV 2) ) AS NameNeededHereIThink
          FROM Datatable_CALCULATION
       );

Comment: Thanks. I did remove the comment characters. It keeps telling me that I am missing a )] in that final statement.

Comment: SELECT CALCULATION AS Median
        , a3.MEASURE
        , a3.CALCULATION
  FROM ( SELECT a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION
              , COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) Rank
           FROM Datatable_CALCULATION a1
              , Datatable_0114_CALCULATION a2   
          WHERE a1.CALCULATION < a2.CALCULATION
             OR (a1.CALCULATION=a2.CALCULATION
                 AND  a1.MEASURE  <= a2.MEASURE)
       GROUP BY a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION) a3
  WHERE Rank =((SELECT cint(((COUNT()) DIV 2)) As Median 
       (SELECT ((COUNT()+1) DIV 2) FROM[Datatable_CALCULATION]);

Comment: Install Notepad++ (free) then paste you sql in.  It matches up brackets for you.  you don't have enough and you have the commented line in.  use the text in my new answer

Comment: Thanks. I am steill getting the error message "syntax error in query expression" and this statement is highlighted SELECT cint(((COUNT()) DIV 2)) AS Median
                  FROM[ASUCoreMeasure_0114_CALCULATION]
               )

Comment: OH!   It's DIV.    use / instead.         cint(((COUNT()) / 2)) AS Median

Bugger!

Comment: Thanks you so much. Still getting error. Syntax error missing operator ", COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) RANK " I am not sure operator to but here.

Comment: change to COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) AS RANK

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting another error. Access does not recognize my datatable.CALCULATION.Should I put a comma after the first statement and put datatable.calculation

Comment: So, I removed the field name. from the table description no I am getting the error message that there are the wrong number argument statements in cint(((COUNT()) /2)

Comment: The code in your comment has the wrong number of closing ). Sorry I can't help any further now, I hope you will be able to get it working.  Could you please flag my answer as an accepted answer as I think i t has essentially answered you original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CALCULATION AS Median
     , a3.MEASURE
     , a3.CALCULATION
  FROM (  SELECT a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION
              , COUNT(a1.CALCULATION) Rank
           FROM Datatable_CALCULATION a1
              , Datatable_0114_CALCULATION a2
          WHERE a1.CALCULATION < a2.CALCULATION
             OR (a1.CALCULATION=a2.CALCULATION
            AND a1.MEASURE    <= a2.MEASURE)
       GROUP BY a1.MEASURE
              , a1.CALCULATION
       )
       a3
 WHERE Rank =(
       (SELECT cint(((COUNT()) DIV 2)) AS Median
                  FROM[Datatable_CALCULATION]
               ));
```